# mysql procedure - use result in second query with reformatted date

Tags: mysql, variables, date, format, procedure

I need to create a procedure that:
1) selects some text from a field in a table and stores it in a variable
2) updates the same record field only adding the date in yyyymmdd format plus additional text input into the procedure
...something like this...

```
delimiter //
create procedure table1.sp_updateComment (IN inputIP varchar(15), IN inputAccount varchar(10))
begin
start transaction;
select comment from table1 where ip = inputIP;
update table1 set comment = '<comment from above> + yyyymmdd + inputAccount', status = 'u' where ip = inputIP;
commit;
end;
//
delimiter ;
;
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SELECT...INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html) to select some value and store it in a variable:

```
SELECT comment INTO @my_comment_variable FROM table1 WHERE ip = inputIP;
```

However, it doesn't seem necessary in your case. Try using [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
UPDATE table1
SET comment = CONCAT(comment, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%Y%m%d"), inputAccount'), status = 'u'
WHERE ip = inputIP;
```

Comment: THANK YOU MR. GENIUS PERSON! :)

Comment: Question ... when I call the stored procedure I get back 0 rows affected but it DOES work ?!? I need to be able to programatically detect success / failure.

Comment: 0 rows affected probably means the UPDATE is not updating anything. Check the WHERE condition is as you want it. Also check the data before and after calling the stored procedure, to be sure.

Comment: Oh it's working ... I check before and after and the record gets updated properly.